# get string from nspasteboard

Tags: objective-c, clipboard, nspasteboard

maybe it's been a long night but I am not able to understand how to check the clipboard for strings

I have been reading the NSPasteboard documentation..

could some one help me out?

Comment: This could help: http://www.mobileorchard.com/new-in-iphone-30-tutorial-series-part-3-copy-paste-with-uipasteboard/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

you need to use the following method with [stringForType](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPasteboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with key [NSPasteboardTypeString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPasteboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to read the string value from clipboard.

`- (NSString *)stringForType:(NSString *)dataType` .

```
NSPasteboard*  myPasteboard  = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
NSString* myString = [myPasteboard  stringForType:NSPasteboardTypeString];
```

---

To do this for iOS with UIPasteBoard use the following code:

```
UIPasteboard *thePasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
NSString *pasteboardString = thePasteboard.string;
NSLog(@"%@", pasteboardString);
```

Comment: While NSPasteboard is available in OS X v10.0 and later, there are some issues using NSPasteboardTypeString in OS X v10.5 and earlier. In v10.6, many Pasteboard types with have new UTIs and the constants changed. This is probably ancient history, but worth mentioning. Great answer, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can find the **Swift 4** version on below for both **Mac** and **iOS**.

**Mac**

```
    let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.general
    let copiedString = pasteboard.string(forType: .string)
```

**iOS**

```
    let pasteboard = UIPasteboard.general
    let copiedString = pasteboard.string // might be nil value, is an optional variable
```